# Django 1.11.15 and query string parameters

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to query from django  i.e  http://localhost:8000/search/Tesco/apples to get a query of json list, the one below.

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "Date": "2018-08-02",
        "Title": "Rosedene Farms Small Sweet Apple 520G",
        "Price": 0.96,
        "PricePerWeight": "1.85/kg",
        "FinalOffer": "undefined undefined",
        "ProductID": 292249576
    },
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Tesco', views.TescoView)

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include(router.urls), name='search'),
    url(r'^search/', include(router.urls), name='searchTwo')
```

my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Tesco
from .serializers import TescoSerializers
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse


class TescoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Tesco.objects.filter(Title__icontains='apple')
    serializer_class = TescoSerializers
```

how would I get the URL  http://localhost:8000/search/tesco/ to query through the database for the list of json?

Comment: still have better ways to do that like ?q=tesco try this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think searching like:

```
http://localhost:8000/search/Tesco/apples
```

is a normal pattern in Django Rest Framework (DRF), so I think you're going to hit a lot of resistance trying to make this pattern work with DRF.  If I may suggest, I believe you're in the [X-Y Problem space](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - ["That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/138799)

Normally, filtering parameters are specified on the listing view of the model. For your model, your complete Tesco instance listing can be found at:

```
http://localhost:8000/Tesco/
```

If you want to filter this down, you append query parameters after a `?` like:

```
http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?title__icontains=apple
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?ProductID=292249576
```

or multiple searching filters like:

```
http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?ProductID=292249576&title__icontains=apple
```

To use *this* pattern, you need to modify your viewset and add a [FilterSet](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filterset.html).  This is what your views.py file would look like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Tesco
from .serializers import TescoSerializers
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy, reverse
# Import filtering libraries
import django_filters 
from rest_framework import filters


class TescoFilterSet(django_filter.FilterSet):
    title__icontains = django_filter.Filter('Title', lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Tesco
        fields = ('title__icontains', 'ProductID')


class TescoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Tesco.objects.filter(Title__icontains='apple')
    serializer_class = TescoSerializers

    # Hook up filterset
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = TescoFilterSet

    # allow ordering on any field
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

In my experience the nginx and apache webservers seem to work well with this pattern when you get to content caching.

For more on filtering, see the [DRF guide on Filtering.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

## Ordering

Per your comment, you can order by specifying `order_fields` as seen above.  Then you can add the `ordering` parameter.

```
                                                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
 http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?title__icontains=apple&ordering=price
```

This will be ascending price.

Add a `-` before `price` and the order is reversed or descending:

```
 http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?title__icontains=apple&ordering=-price
                                                              ^
```

Comment: Thanks, its what i needed. However, is there any way i can get the list of items ordered on their prices. If i type in http://localhost:8000/Tesco/?title__icontains=apple. I want to get all the items ordered from lowest to biggest